# How can I extract the code(content) of a <script>-Tag

Tags: node.js, selenium, steambot

So I want to get the content of a script-Tag. I tried getAttribute, getText and other functions and variables, but it didn't work. I might have used them the wrong way.

This is my code:

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

    (async function example() {
    
        const screen = {
            width: 1080,
            height: 720
        };
    
        let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').setFirefoxOptions(new firefox.Options().windowSize(screen)).build();
    
        await driver.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29');
    
        let script = driver.findElements(By.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]/script[3]'));
        
    
        script.then(() => {
            console.log(script);
        });
        
    })();
```

And instead of getting the script-Tag Content, I only get *undefined*.

This should be the result or atleast the most imporant part of it:

```
var g_rgAppContextData = {"730":{"appid":730,"name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","icon":"https:\/\/cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/730\/69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4.jpg","link":"https:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/app\/730"}};
        var g_rgAssets = {"730":{"2":{"20536774541":{"currency":0,"appid":730,"contextid":"2","id":"20536774541","classid":"4288109779","instanceid":"188530139","amount":"0","status":4,"original_amount":"1","unowned_id":"20536774541","unowned_contextid":"2","background_color":"","icon_url":"-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhjxszJemkV09-5lpKKqPrxN7LEmyVQ7MEpiLuSrYmnjQO3-UdsZGHyd4_Bd1RvNQ7T_FDrw-_ng5Pu75iY1zI97bhLsvQz","icon_url_large":"-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhjxszJemkV09-5lpKKqPrxN7LEm1Rd6dd2j6eQ9N2t2wK3-ENsZ23wcIKRdQE2NwyD_FK_kLq9gJDu7p_KyyRr7nNw-z-DyIFJbNUz","descriptions":[{"type":"html","value":"Zustand: Einsatzerprobt"},{"type":"html","value":" "},{"type":"html","value":"Als eines der beliebtesten Sturmgewehre der Welt ist das AK-47 sehr stark und zuverl\u00e4ssig. Mit kurzen, kontrollierten Feuerst\u00f6\u00dfen ist diese Waffe besonders t\u00f6dlich. Die Waffe wurde durch Wassertransferdruck mit einem Carbonfasermuster und einem roten Nadelstreifen versehen.\n\n<i>Haben Sie keine Angst, ans Limit zu gehen<\/i>"},{"type":"html","value":" "},{"type":"html","value":"Kollektion \u201ePhoenix\u201c","color":"9da1a9"},{"type":"html","value":" "}],"tradable":0,"actions":[{"link":"steam:\/\/rungame\/730\/76561202255233023\/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M3458169751030842393A%assetid%D7227257513868423029","name":"Im Spiel untersuchen \u2026"}]
```

I hope that you can help me with this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that's the right xpath.

Comment: use getAttribute("innerHTML") on the webelement.   But findElements will return an array of webelements.  You sure you wanted to use that instead of findElement?

Comment: /html/body/div[1]/div[7]/script is what I get when I copy it's xpath.

Comment: I checked the xpath again and its correct. "/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/script" This is for another script, but thanks.They script I want is the last script on this site.
I don't know why, but I can't use getAttribute("innerHTML") on it and I don't get an element with findElement, but I just don't understand why.

Comment: Update: I don't know why, but the xpaths from the MozillaFirefox-Tool aren't correct. Do you maybe know a tool, to get the correct xpath or a xpath that I can use in selenium.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update2.0: I think I've found a way to get the script element, but I always get Prommise { <pending> } and not the value of it. A problem is that there is always a different count of script-Tags on this site. It stays to a count of scripts for 5-7 reloads and then it goes to a higher count for 2-3 page reloads so I just try this more often that I always get the right script-Object.

Comment: You can return an array of webelement references that match <script>.  Then iterate through the elements using getAttribute("innerHTML") to check for an expected value.  (meaning whatever it is that is unique to the script you want...)